# backspace is not working for onkeyPress event in firefox

Tags: javascript, php, html

`Backspace` is not working for `onKeyPress` event in firefox

```
<input type="text" id="txt1"  onKeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'  maxlength="10" onkeyup="functionname()"/>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `onkeydown` instead due to better support in browsers.

The code for **Backspace** is **8**, and it's out of your range.

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine :

```
return ( event.charCode == 0 ) || ( event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57)
```

Comment: I would add code snippet to show that it truly works.